# Sign up with multiple forms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel and in my website I need to make a registration throw many steps. There is a first view where the user enter his information and a profile picture then a second view to choose the account type and a third view to pay the inscription fee with Paypal. 
I want to get all the information in the final view by using `Input::all()`, I hope there is an easy way to do that

Comment: just create 1 form and hide/show bits of it with js.

Comment: Hello,

Thats a cool way to divide registration steps. 
You can write one catch file for the first steps, at final step just get that all records, and execute query for the registration

Comment: @user3540050 thanks for the comment, what is exactely a catch file?

Comment: catche file is just for the temparory file, and in that file you can add all your post variable name based on defined structure. and so on

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself by creating a php class which stores all this data and then create an object of this class and store that in a session.

```
class data{
    public $data1;
    public $data2;
    public $data3;
    //must checks if the data is complete
    function checkdata(){
        if(condition){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
//Store data in session or load existing data from session.
if(isset($_SESSION["data"]){
    $data = $_SESSION["data"];
}else{
    $data = new data();
    $_SESSION["data"] = $data;
}
//do with the data whatever needs to be done. change the variables if needed etc.
$data->$data1 = $_POST["data1"];
//once all data is complete send and save it where it needs to be saved and unset the session
if($data->checkdata()){
    saveorsenddata($data);
    unset($_SESSION["data"]);
}//else do nothing
```

Comment: using the session all data is available on all pages.

Comment: That was the first idea that I had also with laravel you can easily do that using View::make('page2')->with('input1', $input1) and the you will have the data available only for the next page, but I'm looking for a better way to do that

Comment: I didn't find an easier way to make a form run over multiple pages than this method, but maybe there is with laravel or other libraries